# Derivatives of Fourier Coefficients Recovery Transformation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\{z\mapsto e_i(z)\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ and define the map $\mathscr{F}$ be the map from $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R})$ into $\ell^2$ by
$$
\mathscr{F}\triangleq f(x)\mapsto \left(
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(z)e_i(z) dm(z)
\right)_{i \in \mathbb{N}},
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Then what would the Frechet derivatives of $\mathscr{F}$ be and when do they exist?

Comment: It is a linear operator, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\mathscr{F}[f+t g] = ?$

Comment: So its it equal to itself?